# Disconnect a user from VC with a userID discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am having a tough time understanding the discord.js documentation. I am looking to have my bot disconnect a user based on their userID.

My code would ideally look something like this:

```
function disconnectUser(userID){
   userID.disconnect();
   return;
}
```

The code I have tried is varitions of:

```
function disconnectUser(userID){
   userID.VoiceState.disconnect();
   return;
}
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'disconnect')
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voice is not an attribute of "users", it is only a member of "guild.members". "guild.members" is created when a user joins a VC and is accessed via a message or an interaction. In my case using slash commands I got the guild by passing in the interaction to the disconnectUser() function. The working disconnect function works as below:

```
async function disconnectUser(userID, interaction){
    let user = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(userID);
    user.voice.disconnect();
}
```

Where interaction is essentially the same as message.

Answer (score 1):

## Discord.js v13

You simply need to fetch the member and the call the `voiceState#disconnect()` method on them like so:

```js
async function disconnect(userID){
let user = await client.users.fetch(userID)
user.voice.disconnect();
}
```

For calling it you simply need to pass a snowflake ( user ID) as the function parameter like so:

```js
disconnect(1234567890123456);
```

## Discord.js v12

The `voiceState#disconnect()` method was called [`voiceState#kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=kick) in v12 therefore you'd have to make the suitable changes if on v12.

Like so:

```js
async function disconnect(userID){
let user = await client.users.fetch(userID)
user.voice.kick();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! Unfortunately I am getting some errors with you implementation. When I use it verbatim I get this error:
"(let user = await message.guild.members.fetch(userID)
^ReferenceError: message is not defined)"

When I changed the fetch statement to: "let user = client.users.fetch(userID)" I got this error instead, which is the same as above. "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'disconnect')"
Any ideas?

Comment: Edited my post, please refer for your suitable version, it used to be voice.kick() in v12, I gave an answer according to the latest version that's why it differs appearently, make sure to mention your version from next time  welcome to stackoverflow lol

Comment: Whoops my bad! I am on discord.js v13.1.0 and still get Type error when using your corrected v13 block

Comment: Hmmm that's kinda weird try console logging `user.voice`

Comment: Got some more help. Turns out it was an issue of finding the guild! If you're interested I put a new solution up with my solution. Thank you for your help, it got me going in the right direction!